# two for loops - how do I run

Tags: python, selenium

I'm running this on Python (selenium):

I can run this successfully for one iteration after that, it doesn't recognise the outer loop and shows an error.

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="dtree0"]/div/a')
names=[]
for elem in elements:
    names.append(elem.text)
    print(names)

 for id in range (2, 170):
        for i in range(0, len(elements)):
            elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath ('//*[@id="dtree0"]/div/a')
            elem = elements[i]
    #     #         # only click the elements in the names list (this level)
            if elem.text in names:
                try:
                    elem.click()
                except WebDriverException:
                     pass  # ignore if elem is not clickable
            # browser.find_elements_by_id("stree2").click()
            my_id = "stree{}".format(id)
            browser.find_element_by_id(my_id).click()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath (
                    '/html/body/center[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a[1]/img').click ()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath ('/html/body/center[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/input').click ()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath ('/html/body/center/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[5]/a').click ()
            sleep (5)
            browser.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="personas"]/b').click ()
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu_personas"]/a[2]').click()
```

How can I modify this so that it runs both of these for loops on every iteration.

The error is as follows: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

I believe this is because the "Stree" part is not being understood by the program since the outer for loop is not working.

The webpage looks like this: [image]

The folders part is the "elements" and the "id" part are the files. I want to open the folders and download the files all of them.

Comment: what error shows?

Comment: You are rebinding `elements` in your inner loop. I don't know what you expect (since you didn't bother posting a proper [mcve]), but this certainly won't work as expected anyway...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers what does rebinding mean? I edited to show the error.

Comment: @ChristianSloper I edited to show an error.

Comment: rebinding => re-assigning.

Answer (score 0):

You get the length of elements and then change elements by assigning to it inside the loop. This is because of your double use of elements. It should be 2 different variables.

```
for id in range (2, 170):
    for i in range(0, len(elements)):
        elements_2 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath ('//*[@id="dtree0"]/div/a')
        elem = elements_2[i]
```

That is if the second loop is inside the first loop. Your indentation is unclear.

Comment: yes, the second loop is inside the first one. But the problem is that in the second iteration it only considers the inner loop and so doesn't recognise the "my_id" line of code.

Comment: Did you try the change elements_2 in my example?

Comment: yes, still it shows error in the "stree" line of code

Comment: You mean in the line my_id = "stree{}".format(id)? And is 11111 the error or do you have more information?

Comment: yes. I think it is not running the outer loop in the second iteration?

Comment: Put some print statements inside the loops then you know more about what's going on.

Comment: I do not have more information apart from the error

Comment: but is that logic correct? that if you have two loops it is going to complete the innermost first and the go to the outer one in recursive fashion

Comment: this is on selenium and so I can see the webpage, it doesn't do anything on the second iteration.

Comment: The inner loop always finishes and then the next iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: With print statements you can trace your program, no need to see the webpage. You could edit your example to get the right indentation. Now it looks like you have 3 loops inside each other. Is that how it should be? If you want to see the webpage use selenium with chromedriver.

Comment: Without any further information you won't get any results. Tip 1: place a lot of print statements print('loop 1'), print('loop 2') print( whatever will help you) inside your code so you can see what is happening. Tip 2: Use an IDE like PyCharm to develop your program. It contains a debugger so you can step through your progam and inspect all the variables. It needs time to learn but it's worth it.